# Parsing If Statement with SpiderMonkey - Type Error

Tags: javascript, parsing, spidermonkey

I am currently using spiderMonkey to parse some JavaScript scripts and obtain their respective ASTs. I've already done this with assignment expressions and the sort, however when I try to parse if statements, I get the following error when performing a pre order traversal of the AST produced:

```
TypeError: root is undefined
```

My code for performing the pre order traversal is as follows:

```
function printTreePreOrder(root)
{


    currentNodeSequence.push(root.type);

    if(root.left!=null)
    {
        printTreePreOrder(root.left);
    }

    if(root.right!=null)
    {
        printTreePreOrder(root.right);
    } 

}
```

My expected outcome would be to have root.type = "IfStatement". I am using the Mozilla Parser API as a basis for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API#Built-in_objects

Could anyone identify what the problem is? Is it the way I am trying to access the type?

This is the script I am currently trying to parse:

```
if(a>b)
     a=2;
else
     b=3;
```

Furthermore, I am using Reflect.parse to parse the script and obtain its AST. This AST is then passed to the above method (as the parameter root)

Comment: It's that `root` is undefined.

Comment: root should store the AST after parsing the script using Reflect.parse. How is the AST undefined?! (edited question to show the script I am trying to parse)

Comment: ... *How* is it undefined? I don't know--you don't show the code that calls `printTreePreOrder`. But from the limited information you provide, `root` is undefined within that method.

Comment: `!=` coerces types confusingly and is never useful. It's better to use `!==`.